# Button Clicks Get Stuck on Android Widget if Http Call takes time to return

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-pendingintent

My Widget has two buttons for right and left navigation with in the widget. If I have a set of data then I switch between data using left and right arrow button. To update data I make a Http Call every minute. If http call takes time to return, my button clicks start getting accumulated and get suddenly fired in series after a pause of 7-8 seconds. I am using pendingIntents for buttons and receiving it in broadcast receiver of widget.

Button clicks work fine if HTTP call is fast.

But if HTTP call is slow to return, and I click on let say 10 times on right arrow, while clicking nothing will happen and after 7-8 secs 10 clicks will be fired in a flash.

Please suggest how can I stop my button clicks getting blocked and then getting fired in a row.

Is the slowness of HTTP call the actual reason of buttons getting stuck ?

Comment: better use async task and make the http call in your doInBackground() method.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make HTTP call from your UI thread, so make sure you use an AsyncTask to perform any i/O or networking operation.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your doing the HTTP request on the UI thread which is not a good idea as HTTP request can take time as can other network tasks or I/O tasks, and android will detect this and may present the user with ANR message (App not responding) and ask the user if they want to force close the app.

You would need to run the HTTP request within an ASyncTask that the onclick event would fire. This way, a new thread would be created for the HTTP stuff while the user interface can carry on working and accepting user input instead of locking.

Comment: Hi, I am already using a different thread for HTTP request. Just that instead of AsyncTask I am using Normal JAVA Thread and Runnable.
Plus I tried using AsyncTask also, the behavior remains similar.
This stucking behavior happens only on slower networks.

Comment: I don't think that works, I can't remember the exact reason but I remember having this problem. It needs to run in an ASyncTask and all the work is done within the doInBackground method